# Jenkins pipelines Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm having problems with my Jenkinsfile.
I want to list all running workers in current job, but jenkins just fails without printing any error. Code snippet:

```
@NonCPS  
def check_running_process() {
  // Check if PR build already in progress to kill old one
  def pull_id = env.ghprbPullId.toInteger()
  println pull_id
  def current_build_id  = env.BUILD_ID.toInteger()
  println current_build_id
  def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('jobname')
  println currentJob
}
```

Output:
`[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
47`

So Jenkins stops at `def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('jobname')`
There is no error produced, just a build fail.
There are no errors in jenkins.log file.
This works in scripting console.
Did anyone had the same problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was my problem.
I was calling `check_running_process()` inside `try` handler.
This produced no error, but failed because
`method jenkins.model.Jenkins getItemByFullName java.lang.String`
signature was not approved
(nor it produced script approval request).